# Excel averaging to scores

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

I want to calculate students' grade average for assignments from excel. I need to follow the 8 best out of 9 formula.

I saw this formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(G2:O2>SMALL(G2:O2,1),G2:O2))
```

which will exclude the lowest grade. If the student didn't submit 2 assignments this will exclude both 0 grade and not 1. How can I adjust this to exclude only a single lowest grade?

A simple example of an excel with the row `1,2,3,1` should yield a 3 best average of 2. with this formula I get 2.5.

```
=AVERAGE(IF(A1:D1>SMALL(A1:D1,1),A1:D1))
```

Attaching screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one has Excel O365, try:

```
=AVERAGE(LARGE(A1:D1,SEQUENCE(COUNT(A1:D1)-1)))
```

And if there are potential zeros involved you need to discard:

```
=AVERAGE(LARGE(A1:D1,SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(A1:D1,">0")-1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply remove the zeroes, something like:

```
=AVERAGE(AND(NOT(G2:O2=0);IF(G2:O2>SMALL(G2:O2,1)),G2:O2))
```

Comment: No. The zeros will lower the point grade. If a student did not submit more than one assignment his average should go down.